# Can kerberos be setup to utilize openldap?

Tags: ldap, wso2, kerberos, openldap

The following page (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS450/Kerberos+Security) indicates that kerberos be used with WSO2 with the embedded LDAP.  We are using an external OpenLDAP user store. Can kerberos be setup on an external OpenLDAP? If possible please direct to an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the MIT Kerberos pages clearly state that there is a possibility to configure Kerberos with openldap. Have a look at http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/krb5-1.11/doc/admin/conf_ldap.html. (Which was the first result of a search on my favourite Internet search engine for "kerberos openldap"....)

That of course only applies to the basic MIT Kerberos. As WSO2 has its own implementation you might have bad luck there. But as their solution is based onto ApacheDS there might be a way of redirecting a subtree inside the ApacheDS to your OpenLDAP via referral. You might have to dig deeper into "ldap referral".